# disable thumb.db on windows 10 network folder

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, thumbs.db

I know this question has been asked million times on the net, but no registry approach or group policies approach I found works in Windows 10 for network drives with Windows Version from Mai 2018.

I have several 50+ folders with few images inside and I want to rename them. However 8/10 times I get the notice

> the action cannot be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program

I can see that thumb.db files are created. I assume this is the cause of the problem.

So how can I fix it for a current windows 10 system for network drives.

Links I have tried

https://mikebeach.org/2013/01/05/disable-thumbs-db-creation-on-network-drives-in-windows/

https://www.howtogeek.com/210764/fix-file-in-use-deletion-errors-on-network-drives-by-disabling-windows-thumbnail-generation/

Comment: The second like says the opposite. Can you prove the statement somehow?

Comment: As a workaround, try to disconnect and reconnect to the network drive and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Windows Version 10.0.18363.1198), I faced the same issue. I have no solution for switching off the generation of the `thumbs.db` files, but as you want to rename your folders and cannot because of `thumbs.db` files, try **moving** them away (delete would fail however).

My workaround is to move the `thumbs.db` file(s) from the network folders to a local folder (e.g. "c:\scrap"); there they can be overwritten and deleted.

If you are dealing with a lot of folders ("50+"), you can use FileExplorer's search function (or something more versatile like AgentRansack) to find all `thumbs.db`s in your folder structure and then move them in one go.